# iOS 6.x: Changing UITextField Font Property Dynamically Causes Cursor To Get Lost

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uitextfield

With iOS 6.x, if you ask to be notified for a `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`, and then size the font in that notification, the cursor gets confused and draws itself in the wrong place.

```
@implementation MyTextField

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder])
    {
        [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self
                                               selector:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
                                                   name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                                 object:self];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)textFieldDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20 - self.text.length];
}

@end
```

This wasn't a problem with iOS 5.x.  Any workarounds to get the cursor to reset/redraw itself when this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

in textFieldDidChange, after self.font = .... Don't know if it will help, but it might be a quick workaround.